# Application showing installed but still not showing up in dashboard

Tags: unity-dash

I have faced this problem a lot of time. I have installed an app from sw center but its still not showing up in dashboard. Like I installed GCC and its showing as installed but not getting how to open it. So tell me how to solve this problem for once and for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All program do not have a graphical interface. It does not make sense to have a launchers for programs like that.

gcc is one of these programs.

You can invoke them from the terminal. Start the terminal and start the program from there.

Comment: Then how to use gcc and is there any other good C/C++ compiler. I used to use Dev C++ on windows.

Comment: `gcc -o program program.c`. But I think that what you are after is a IDE, like kdevelop, anjuta, eclipse etc.

Comment: I dont need eclipse or netbeans for this... That I use for java and adnroid. What I need is something like Dev C++, which is available for linux but even not getting how to use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

go back an click on More-info button in sw center (in your case you will find it in installed->#categories#->yourApp) to see if there is dependics libraries for graphical interface