# RipperX installed but not showing up in Dash

Tags: 15.10, unity-dash

I've just installed RipperX from Synaptic.

The program is installed:-

```
carl@number5:~$ which ripperx
/usr/bin/ripperx
```

And will run with `ripperx` from the terminal.

But it does not appear in the Dash at all.

The closest question to this is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240086/application-showing-installed-but-still-not-showing-up-in-dashboard) but that relates to non-GUI applications.

Is there something I need to do to get it to show up in Dash, or is this a bug/problem with RipperX itself?

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67373/search-for-applications-not-in-path-from-unity-dash) has been suggested as a duplicate but the answer links to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available/), which starts with the caveat **Please note that right now, most of the information contained below is outdated and cannot be updated. Be careful, most of this won't work on Ubuntu 12.04 and newer**. I am running 15.10

Additional:-

```
carl@number5:~$ sudo find /usr -iname ripperx.desktop
[sudo] password for carl: 
/usr/share/applications/ripperx.desktop
carl@number5:~$
```

Comment: Possible dublicate of this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/67373/search-for-applications-not-in-path-from-unity-dash

Comment: Could you show the results of `sudo find /usr -iname ripperx.desktop` ?

Comment: @andrew.46 Added to the question.

Comment: So the desktop file is in place and as long as it looks like this: http://pastebin.com/Y8KYJVce it should all be good, and certainly this works on my system. Log out and in should be enough, I am puzzled :(.

Comment: I've rebooted a few times since, and it now works fine. Bit strange that it didn't work initially though.